# Can I download and rename a file from .abc to .json in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to take a json file (.json) and rename it to my app's file type (.abc) and then attach it to an email and then open this file up in another instance of my app and then read this .json file.

Would this be possible?  i.e. can I take this file save it and rename it back to .json and then read it using a json parser all within my running iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **yes**, but why bother with extensions? Anyways, take a look at these NSFileManager methods :

```
– replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:
– moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:
– moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:
```

Comment: You have to have your own app extension to open it with your app under iOS 4, I believe, and so .json could be used by another.